# Como limitar a geração de números pseudo-aleatórios a números diferentes de zero e não repetidos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Gostaria que os números não se repetissem e fossem diferentes de zero.

```
import random


Sort1 = int(60 * random.random())   


Sort2 = int(60 * random.random())


Sort3 = int(60 * random.random())

Sort4 = int(60 * random.random())

Sort5 = int(60 * random.random())

Sort6 = int(60 * random.random())

lista = [Sort1,Sort2,Sort3,Sort4,Sort5,Sort6]

lista.sort()


print (Sort1,Sort2,Sort3,Sort4,Sort5,Sort6)


print (lista)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> random.sample(range(1,61), 6)
[39, 15, 37, 18, 52, 60]
```

Explicação:

Um método que garante um sorteio justo (i.e. cada elemento tem a mesma chance de ser sorteado) e sem repetição é a geração de uma permutação do espaço de busca - por exemplo pelo [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) - da qual se retira apenas os primeiros `k` elementos que se quer.

Se seu espaço de busca é pequeno, [a implementação proposta pelo Luiz Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173806/215) (criar uma lista com todos os elementos e permutá-la) é a maneira mais simples e talvez mais eficiente. Na sua pergunta, os números vão apenas de `1` a `60`, então essa solução simples é a que eu usaria. Se você não tiver acesso ao numpy, pode usar também a função [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
>>> nums = list(range(1, 61))
>>> random.shuffle(nums)
>>> nums[:6]
[14, 12, 56, 26, 42, 10]
```

Por outro lado, caso o espaço de busca fosse muito grande (ex.: você quer 10 números de 1 a 1 bilhão) essa implementação ficaria inviável - nem tanto pelo tempo mas pela memória gasta na criação da lista. Nesse caso, uma implementação alternativa seria:

```
def random_elements(a_sortear, total):
    state = {}
    for i in range(a_sortear):
        # Troca o state[i] com um elemento aleatório
        swap_with = random.randint(i, total - 1)
        state[i], state[swap_with] = state.get(swap_with, swap_with), state.get(i, i)
    return [state[i]+1 for i in range(a_sortear)]

print (random_elements(10, 1000000000))
```

<sup>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978109/520779) (adaptado)</sup>

Trata-se de uma aplicação parcial do mesmo algoritmo:

1. Em vez da lista ser criada explicitamente, fica implícito que o elemento de índice `i` possui o valor `i` caso ele esteja ausente do conjunto:

   ```
   state.get(swap_with, swap_with) # O valor padrão, se ausente, é o próprio índice
   ```
2. Quando dois elementos são trocados (tal qual o algoritmo original), eles são colocados explicitamente no conjunto:

   ```
   state[i], state[swap_with] = state.get(swap_with, swap_with), state.get(i, i)
   ```
3. O algoritmo para de permutar quando o número de elementos desejado já foi obtido:

   ```
   for i in range(a_sortear): # Não vai até total, mas para em a_sortear
       swap_with = random.randint(i, total - 1) # Sorteia de 0 a total-1
       ...
   ```
4. Para o resultado ir de `1` a `N`, em vez de `0` a `N-1`, desloca todo o conjunto 1 para a direita:

   ```
   return [state[i]+1 for i in range(a_sortear)]
   ```

Ou seja, nessa implementação tanto o tempo quanto a memória gasta são proporcionais ao número de elementos que se quer, em vez do total de elementos disponíveis para serem sorteados.

Por fim, há o algoritmo alternativo em que simplesmente se sorteia vários números e, caso algum venha repetido, o sorteio é feito de novo até que todos os resultados sejam diferentes. Esse método pode ser até mais eficiente que a aplicação parcial do Fisher-Yates, quando o conjunto total é muito grande (já que a chance de colisão é pequena). As respostas [do Ícaro Dantas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173804/215) e [do Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173836/215) dão exemplos de implementação.

O uso de `random.sample` - pelo que eu entendi dos [fontes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L282) - escolhe uma ou outra implementação baseado no que seria mais eficiente conforme os tamanhos do conjunto total e do número de elementos a ser sorteado.

Comment: Ja tinha upado a do Luiz Vieira, mas estava esperando uma alternativa com F-Y "moderado" mesmo (espero que o pessoal note a sutileza de embaralhar só o numero de ítens necessários). Sendo assim, +1 também!

Answer (score 11):

Se você deseja números não repetidos em um intervalo ([1, 60], pelo seu exemplo), uma solução bem simples é fazer uma [permutação aleatória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permuta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_aleat%C3%B3ria). Usando o numpy é bem fácil com a função [`numpy.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.random.permutation(np.arange(1, 61))
print(nums)
```

Esse código funciona assim:

1. A chamada `np.arange(1, 61)` gera uma lista com números de 1 a 60 (porque você disse que os números não devem ser 0 - se puder ter o 0, basta passar diretamente o número máximo+1 à chamada de `np.random.permutation` a seguir).
2. Essa lista serve de entrada para à chamada `np.random.permutation`, que apenas pega essa lista e embaralha as posições.

Exemplo de resultado da execução do código:

```
[ 3 37 59 54 58 16  1 19 36 40 34 31 18 13 25 50 23  9 41 46 27  8 15 47 24
 29 57 43 56 22 11 48 26 39  7 17 55 21 20 42 30 35 32 14 12 28 33 53 38 60
  2 52 44 45  6 49 10  5 51  4]
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mas não é necessário reinventar a roda - há [uma função pronta pra isso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), na biblioteca padrão do Python mesmo (i.e. sem precisar do numpy). Mais detalhes na [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173843/215).

Comment: Show de bola, @mgibsonbr. Eu não sabia dessa função! :)

Answer (score 4):

Aqui fica outra alternativa, usando um [set](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html), este por default implementado na própria linguagem python já evita duplicados.

No exemplo em baixo `n` é o número de entradas que queres na tua nova lista, coloquei 6 baseado no código que colocaste na pergunta:

```
from random import randint

lista = set()
n = 6

while len(lista) < n:
    lista.add(randint(1, 60))

lista = sorted(lista) # transformar em lista e ordenar
print(lista)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/aGx0CH)

Muita atenção, se por acaso colocares número maximo random menor que `n`, ex: 5, vais ficar em loop infinito, para cobrires essa hipótese podes fazer:

```
from random import randint

lista = set()
n = 6
max_random = 60

if(max_random > n):
    while len(lista) < n:
        lista.add(randint(1, max_random))
    print(sorted(lista)) # transformar em lista e ordenar
else:
    print('O numero random não pode ser menor que n')
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mas há [uma função pronta pra isso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) que inclusive escolhe entre a sua solução e [a solução do Luiz Vieira](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173806/215) dependendo de qual seria mais eficiente conforme o tamanho das entradas. Mais detalhes na [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173843/215).

Comment: Sem duvida a melhor solução @mgibsonbr , obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isto resolve seu problema:

```
from random import randint

lista = []

n = 40

for i in range(n):
    num = randint(1, 60) # Intervalo de 1 a 60.
    while num == 0 or num in lista:
        num = randint(1, 60)
    lista.append(num)

lista.sort()

print lista
```

Comment: Cuidado ao colocar o "n" muito grande, ele pode rodar por muito tempo ou até infinitamente.

Comment: +1 pela boa resposta, mas vc tem toda a razão quanto a ele possivelmente rodar "infinitamente". Por isso o ideal nesses casos é fazer uma permutação aleatória mesmo (pois assim se garante o tempo de execução finito e não se faz laços desnecessários). :)